# Unspecific linker issue in XCode along with x86_x64 undefined symbols that confuse me

Tags: c++, xcode

so I've had this issue for a couple days and have no idea what I am doing wrong. I assume it has something to do with my class declarion of setCard() but I can not for the life of me figure out why this error is popping up. If anyone could just push me in the right direction that would be great.

Here is the class definition that the error starts from:

```
class Card
{
    public:
        Card();
        void setCard(int, char);
        int getFace();
        char getSuit();
        void displayCard();

    private:
        int faceValue;
        char suit;
};
```

Here is the Deck Class:

```
 class DeckOfCards
{
public:
DeckOfCards();

Card draw();
void shuffle();
bool isEmpty();

private:
static const int MAX_CARDS = 52;       //Maximum number of cards in a 
deck
static const int NUM_SUITS = 4;        //Number of card suits
static const int CARDS_PER_SUIT = 13;  //Number of cards of each suit

Card deck[MAX_CARDS];     //The deck of cards
int topCard;              //The subscript of the card on the top of the 
deck

};
```

And then the constructor where the error is called and for some reason will not function:

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
{
//An array of the 4 possible values for the card suit
char suitVals[NUM_SUITS] = { 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' };

int cardSub = 0;    //subscript to process the deck of cards

//Go through all 52 spots in the array of Cards and put a card
//at the location

for( int suitSub = 0; suitSub < NUM_SUITS; suitSub++ )
{
    //For each of the suits, put in all of the cards for the suit
    for( int faceVal = 1; faceVal <= CARDS_PER_SUIT; faceVal++ )
    {
        //Put the card into the deck
        deck[ cardSub ].setCard( faceVal, suitVals[suitSub] );

        //Move to the next card in the deck
        cardSub++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the output or a screenshot of the compilation error you see.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/l8k2L

Comment: What is the type of `deck`? Where is the implementation of `Card`? These pieces of information are important to understand what's going on.